Is there a resource that describes the RPC API in more detail?
I'm trying to understand the API as it is provided by developer.bitcoin.org, but I don't quite understand what some of the commands actually do and require.

The best documentation for Bitcoin Core's JSON-RPC interface is arguably the help command. For example, to get help on the getblocktemplate command, run help getblocktemplate.

this is helpful, but it's also basically the same as the api as provided by developer.bitcoin.org, just with less explanation than the website unfortunately. I'm using a few more sites for research too so hopefully i'll figure it out

You can find an overview of the Bitcoin Core RPC commands on bitcoincore.org.
Please open an issue if you find specific shortcomings in the documentation in the Bitcoin Core repository.
